# How to output "bool(true)" using "var_dump((bool) Yes)" in the example bellow?

Tags: php, boolean

I need to convert 'Yes' to boolean so 'True' would be the same as 'Yes'.
And for 'No' as 'False'.

But in the example below, even if I cast 'Yes' to (bool), still gives warnning and doesn't recognize 'No' as 'False'.

**Expected Results**

```
<?php 

echo var_dump((bool) Yes) . "<br>";
echo var_dump((bool) No) . "<br>";      

/*

 output: 

  bool(true)
  bool(false)

*/

?>
```

**Unexpected Results**

```
<?php 

echo var_dump((bool) Yes) . "<br>";
echo var_dump((bool) No) . "<br>";

/*

output:

Warning: Use of undefined constant Yes - assumed 'Yes'      
(this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in /opt/lampp/htdocs/php-net/test.php on line 15
bool(true) 

Warning: Use of undefined constant No - assumed 'No'      
(this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in /opt/lampp/htdocs/php-net/test.php on line 17
bool(true) 

*/

?>
```

Comment: what in your oppinition is the value of this  `Yes` thing is in this example code: `var_dump((bool) Yes)` before casting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define YES and NO like this

```
define("YES", TRUE);
define("Yes", TRUE);
define("yes", TRUE);

define("NO", FALSE);
define("No", FALSE);
define("no", FALSE);
var_dump(YES);
var_dump(Yes);
var_dump(yes);

var_dump(NO);
var_dump(No);
```

RESULT

```
bool(true)
bool(true)
bool(true)

bool(false)
bool(false)
```

Comment: Thanks  you very much !

Comment: plus echo "<br>"; maybe.